# iexplore.exe - The memory could not be "written"

Tags: memory, freeze, internet-explorer-8, segmentation-fault

Using IE8 I'm randomly getting the error:

> iexplore.exe - Application Error
>
> The instruction at "0x7c0c5a6c" referenced memory at "0x7c0c5a6c". The memory could not be "written". Click on OK to terminate the program. Click on CANCEL to debug the program.

I click OK and IE8 hangs. Any suggestions on what's going on and how to prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

I've see that happen when installing/loading some plugins (namely Flash Player) if IE's memory protection is enabled. Try disabling it (it's in the Advanced settings).

Comment: OK I did that -- I'll wait to see if it worked. If anyone else is looking for the setting it's in the Security category. Scroll to the bottom of the Advanced Tab  (Tools/Internet Options) and uncheck "Enable memory protection to help mitigate online attacks"

Comment: It worked for me: old Windows xp sp2 laptop.. after updating to sp3 and a first batch of system updates, the issue appeared with the Microsoft update site: the error message did show exactly at the same time iexplore asked to install a new Windows update component.

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer add-ons, such as ActiveX controls and browser toolbars, are used by some Web sites to provide an enhanced browsing experience. An error may occur if an add-on is damaged or if an add-on conflicts with Internet Explorer. To determine whether the error is caused by an add-on, run Internet Explorer in "No Add-Ons" mode. To do this, follow these steps:
Click Start, and then type Internet Explorer in the Start Search box.
Click Internet Explorer (No Add-Ons). Internet Explorer opens without add-ons, toolbars, or plug-ins.
Test Internet Explorer to verify that it works correctly. (from Microsoft: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/936213)

You could also stop using IE and switch to Chrome or Firefox!

Comment: If the other answer doesn't work (disabling memory protection) I'll try "No Add-Ons". I use IE8 for my work intranet sites that were designed to use IE8. I use Chrome for typical browsing and Firefox for the add-ons such as Down-Them-All, Firebug, ClickSpeak, ColorZilla, etc.